# How i get the closest input val label and name when i press GET button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html snippet and input are label and content.

=======================================================================

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Nome del campo</label>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="form-control" name="label" value="c">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id_anagrafica" value="184">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Valore</label>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input class="form-control" name="content" value="d">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 16px">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="getInfo(event)">GET</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please describe what you want? Also what you tried till now? add that.

Comment: I want get the values of content and label input when i press GET button. I tried with: `var content = $(event).closest('input[name=content]').val();
`

Comment: all or only one which is closest to the button?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".btn-danger").click(function() {
  console.log("Label " + $(this).parent('div').prev('div').find('label').text())
  console.log("input " + $(this).parent('div').prev('div').find('input').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Nome del campo</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input class="form-control" name="label" value="c">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id_anagrafica" value="184">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Valore</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input class="form-control" name="content" value="d">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 16px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">GET</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. use .parent() to get to parent div then use prev() to get the container of label and input
2. then use .text() to get text of label and .val() to get value of input

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery .change the function with `getInfo(event,this)`

1. Input is there on `previous  div.col-md-2` so call with `prev()`
2. Then apply the `find()` the take that particular element

```js
function getInfo(e,that){
console.log($(that).closest('.col-md-2').prev('.col-md-2').find('.form-control').val())
console.log($(that).closest('.col-md-2').prev('.col-md-2').find('label').text())
console.log($(that).closest('.col-md-2').prev('.col-md-2').find('.form-control').attr('name'))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Nome del campo</label>
    <div class="input">
      <input class="form-control" name="label" value="c">
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id_anagrafica" value="184">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Valore</label>
    <div class="input">
      <input class="form-control" name="content" value="d">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 16px">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="getInfo(event,this)">GET</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value of content you should go up using `closest()` to the div that has the button and the input then using `find()` get the input with the name of `content`

```js
function getInfo(el) {
var content = $(el).closest('.row').find('input[name="content"]').val()
  console.log(content);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Nome del campo</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input class="form-control" name="label" value="c">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id_anagrafica" value="184">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label>Valore</label>
      <div class="input">
        <input class="form-control" name="content" value="d">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 16px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="getInfo(this)">GET</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add input type text in input tag


$(".form-group").each(function(){
  var formVal = $(this).find(".form-control[type='text']").val();
  var formHiddenVal = $(this).find(".form-control[type='hidden']").val();
  var labelTxt = $(this).children("label").text();
});
```